# Not working onChange in react-input-mask (custom input)

Tags: reactjs

Not working onChange in react-input-mask (custom input)

I am not using any libraries as input, but for some reason onChange dont work...

```
<InputMask
  onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)} // dont work...
  disabled={true}
>
  {(props) => {
     return <input type="text" />;
  }}
</InputMask>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mcclintock-w2wzid (demo)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass props inside custom input

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const onHandleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>react-input-mask with Input from Ant D</h1>
      <h2>
        Throwing error: react-input-mask: the following props should be passed
        to the react-input-mask's component and should not be altered in
        children's function: disabled
      </h2>
      <InputMask mask="99/99/9999" value={inputValue} onChange={onHandleChange}>
        {(inputProps) => (
          <input {...inputProps} type="tel" className="" disableUnderline />
        )}
      </InputMask>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Dont work...
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-mcclintock-w2wzid?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @trickysneak i updated ans pls check and working demo is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-greider-mimqll?file=/src/index.js:0-984)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed onChange event doesn’t work without mask prop